# SQL - SELECT the highest value from a group of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, derby

Using a DERBY DB I have something like the following table

```
table = transfers
xid = autoincrement (factor of 10)
PK (xid, phase)

xid     phase      information
------------------------------
10      1          queued
10      2          in progress
10      3          complete
20      1          queued
20      2          in progress
30      1          queued
30      2          in progress
30      11         failed
```

What I want is a query that will extract only the highest phase number for each `xid`. One row for each xid.

In essence the following rows only are pulled back

```
xid     phase      information
------------------------------
10      3          complete
20      2          in progress
30      11         failed
```

SELECT xid, phase, information FROM transfers WHERE .... (help me)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the Max aggregate function

Comment: Can you write an example please?

Comment: Matt has answered it below. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Use `Window Function`

```
SELECT xid,
       phase,
       information
FROM   (SELECT *,Row_number()OVER(partition BY xid ORDER BY phase) Rn               
        FROM   yourtable)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

or use `max` aggregate to find the max `phase` in each `xid` then join the result back to the table.

```
SELECT a.xid,
       a.phase,
       a.information
FROM   yourtable a
       JOIN (SELECT Max(phase) phase,
                    xid
             FROM   yourtable
             GROUP  BY xid) B
         ON a.phase = b.phase
            AND a.xid = b.xid
```

Answer (score 2):

Use MAX and GROUP BY

```
SELECT xid, MAX(phase), information
FROM transfers
GROUP BY xid, information
```

Comment: This won't give the desired result as you group by information too.

Comment: Thanks jpw - I just spotted this too and you're right. Thank you!!

Comment: Matt, your code is wrong.As @jpw says (and I've tried it out too) by including "information" in the group by clause you get more than one "xid" row displayed. I just want one xid displayed so "information" should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
select xid, max(phase), information from transfers group by xid, information
```

Comment: SELECT xid, MAX(phase), information FROM transfers GROUP BY xid - seems to have done the trick